# Canvas does not download at all

Tags: javascript, canvas

So I'm trying to be able to download the canvas, but when I click on my button, nothing happens.

JS:

```
function download() {
var download = document.getElementById("download");
var image = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL("image/png")
    .replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
download.setAttribute("href", image);
//download.setAttribute("download","canvas.png");
}
```

HTML:

`<div id="saveButton""><a href="#" onclick="download()">Download Image</a></div>`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the onclick handler on the anchor tag:

```
<a href="#" onclick="download()">Download Image</a>
```

in your provided JS, `download` is not a function, it is a variable reference to a DOM element.

You also shouldn't be adding the new dataURL to the anchor on click - you should extract the dataURL from the canvas and set the href attribute on load or on application change where the dataURL needs to be updated. getting the canvas' dataURL and setting href on the `onclick` event will cause the initial href(`#`) to be fired rather than the new dataURL. You will also need to set the anchor to have the `download` attribute to signal that it is meant to be downloaded rather than requested as a separate resource.

This should be all you need:

HTML:

```
<div id="saveButton"">
    <a href="#" id="download-anchor" download>Download Image</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
const downloadEl = document.getElementById('download-anchor');
const canvasData = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
downloadEl.setAttribute('href', canvasData);
```

Comment: This does download but it downloads a .html file, when I make the download ```download="img.png"``` it does download a png then, but the format is not supported, when I edit it its my html code lol

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happens because you don't do anything with the "download".
Assuming the `var download = document.getElementById("download");` get's a link / anchor tag...
You then get the image and set the href attibute.... but then nothing, you just have an anchor tag that references the image..
You need to click it.

**Add this line:** `download.click();`.

Here is a function I use for taking screenshots of three.js scenes:

```
function takeScreenshot() {

    // open in new window like this
    //
    var w = window.open('', '');
    w.document.title = "Screenshot";
    //w.document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    var img = new Image();
    // Without 'preserveDrawingBuffer' set to true, we must render now
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    img.src = renderer.domElement.toDataURL();
    w.document.body.appendChild(img);  

/*
    // download file like this.
    //
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    // Without 'preserveDrawingBuffer' set to true, we must render now
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    a.href = renderer.domElement.toDataURL().replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
    a.download = 'canvas.png'
    a.click();
*/

/*
    // New version of file download using toBlob.
    // toBlob should be faster than toDataUrl.
    // But maybe not because also calling createOjectURL.
    //
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    renderer.domElement.toBlob(function(blob){
        var a = document.createElement('a');
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      a.href = url;
      a.download = 'canvas.png';
      a.click();
    }, 'image/png', 1.0);
*/

}
```